# c# TreeView get Parent node Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

On expand asp:treeView How do I get the index that was expended?

I tried to look into: ontreenodeexpanded="Node_Expand"  but I cant find the index of the parent root that was clicked.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The node you expanded is the Node property of the [event arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodeeventargs.aspx):

```
// Inside the event handler method
TreeNode clickedNode = e.Node;
```

You can get its index with the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodecollection.indexof.aspx) method of the [TreeNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodecollection.aspx) that is storing the node.

Comment: srry,for confusing, not the parent node, but when clicking on the (+) symbol to expand the parent node.

Comment: The node has a Parent property that is another node object (or null if it's a root node). Its children are in its Nodes propery (TreeNodeCollection)